# size attribute showing limited items but category products have more than that in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, filter

Size attribute showing limited items in filter navigation but category products have more than that in `Magento 2`. Please see the following images for more details.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Anyone know how to solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be other options product not exists.

Comment: No all products have the same size and more.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values that do not constrict number of product is not shown

For example if all Helmets have XL size than this size will not shown on category page

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not facing this kind of issue. Please confirm is it true.